# datastax enterprise AMI - EC2 is experiencing some issues and has not allocated all of the resources in under 10 minutes

Tags: datastax-enterprise

We have followed the steps to deploy dse in aws as outlined [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/install/installAMI.html).
When configuring the ec2 instance details' under advanced details for user data and adding (replacing values for username and password with correct credentials)

```
--clustername myDSEcluster --totalnodes 6 --version enterprise --username my_name
--password my_password --analyticsnodes 2 --searchnodes 2
```

ec2 instance starts up, however, once we connect to it we see the following in the log:

```
[INFO] 10/09/15-23:59:42 Reflector: Received 1 of 2 responses from: [u'172.31.7.164']
[ERROR] EC2 is experiencing some issues and has not allocated all of the resources in under 10 minutes.

Aborting the clustering of this reservation. Please try again.
[ERROR] Exception seen in ds1_launcher.py:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/ubuntu/datastax_ami/ds1_launcher.py", line 22, in initial_configurations
   ds2_configure.run()
 File "/home/ubuntu/datastax_ami/ds2_configure.py", line 1170, in run
 File "/home/ubuntu/datastax_ami/ds2_configure.py", line 500, in get_seed_list
 File "/home/ubuntu/datastax_ami/ds2_configure.py", line 57, in exit_path
AttributeError: EC2 is experiencing some issues and has not allocated all of the resources in under 10 minutes.

Aborting the clustering of this reservation. Please try again.
```

We tried using different availability zones, then different region, but same results.

Then we tried with the following user data and it worked:

```
--clustername myDSEcluster --totalnodes 1 --version enterprise --username my_name
--password my_password
```

Searching for this type of issue resulted in basically what it says which is AWS is being sluggish to provide the resources this AMI is asking for.

But is there any other way to get this sorted without having to retrying and hoping AWS can respond to requested resources in timely manner?

Comment: Facing the same problem, any solutions?